# Who first found this characterization of Lebesgue integration?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Write $L^1$ for the Banach space $L^1([0, 1])$.  Given $f \in L^1$, define $f_1, f_2 \in L^1$ by
$$
f_1(x) = f(x/2),
\qquad
f_2(x) = f((x + 1)/2).
$$
Let $I = \int_0^1$.  Then $I$ is the unique bounded linear functional on $L^1$ satisfying the equations
$$
I(\text{constant function at }1) = 1,
\qquad
I(f) = (I(f_1) + I(f_2))/2.
$$
This, then, is a simple characterization of integration.

Presumably this has been known for a really long time -- maybe for a century? -- but I'm having trouble tracking it down in the literature.  I simply can't find it anywhere.

Does anyone know anything about the history of this result?

Comment: The only writeup on this topic I've seen is yours.  Probably you know about that one already...

Comment: Well, the integral is already been used to define what $L^1$ is. A simpler way to state this would be to say that the Lebesgue measure is the unique one such that the measure of a set $A\subseteq[0,1]$ is the same as the average of those of $A/2$ and $(A+1)/2$.

Comment: Mariano: re the integral having been used to define $L^1$, that's a good point; thanks.  I'd definitely be interested to know any reference to the characterization of Lebesgue measure that you mention.  On the other hand, putting historical questions aside, there's at least one way to define $L^1$ without knowing what integration is (which I suspect is what Pete's referring to). 

Comment: @Tom: no, I really thought you had some note or something where this result was proved.  I just searched for it and didn't find it.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: Pete: yes, that's what I thought you might have meant.  It's here: http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~tl/glasgowpssl/  Guess I should tidy up my web page a bit...

Comment: I don't know about that result, but the the same result for continuous functions is due to Freyd (http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/20/10/20-10abs.html). If I learned about that paper from a blog post of yours on the n-Category Café, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks, Omar.  I know about Freyd's paper, but I hadn't thought to look at it for references.  (And I don't think I've posted about it!)

Comment: @Tom: my mistake, there it is, and was, when I looked at your page.  Actually I think your webpage is very nice, and I look forward to doing some browsing.

Comment: If instead of $[0,1]$ we think of binary expansions and use $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, then we want the unique Borel measure invariant under the shift map with measures $(1/2,1/2)$ for the sets specified by the first coordinates.  Or something like that.  Maybe related to Borel around 1910 who proposed using Lebesgue measure to model independence in probability?


Comment: @Mariano: L^1([0, 1]) can be defined as the abstract Banach space completion of, say, the step functions on [0, 1] with the L^1 norm (which has a purely finitary description).  This definition technically doesn't require any knowledge of integration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is of help, but I have seen this idea for defining integration elsewhere, specifically on pages 10-11 of Reed and Simon's Functional Analysis. It would go something like this: let $S$ be the space of step functions obtained as linear combinations of characteristic functions of half-open intervals $[k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n)$. Then $S$ is dense in the space $C$ of bounded piecewise continuous functions continuous to the right, with respect to sup norm. By the two conditions, the definition of $I$ is uniquely determined on $S$ and defines a bounded linear functional on $S$ with respect to sup norm, so it uniquely extends to a bounded linear functional on $C$. This in fact defines the Riemann integral $I$, and it's pretty much exactly what Reed and Simon do, except they don't restrict to dyadic rational endpoints.)

(Then, we can go on and define $L^1[0, 1]$ to be the completion of $C$ with respect to the norm given by $f \mapsto I(|f|)$, and since $I$ is a bounded linear functional also with respect to this norm, it extends uniquely to the completion $L^1[0, 1]$.)

**Edit:**: Ah, Reed and Simon mention that this approach to the Riemann integral can be found especifically in Dieudonné, Foundations of Modern Analysis, or in Loomis and Sternberg, Advanced Calculus, Addison-Wesley, 1968. Perhaps one can consult these for further history.

Comment: Thanks, Todd!  That's an excellent start, and Dieudonné sounds especially likely to be useful.   